# table gives me error with tabularx, please help me solve it!

Tags: tables, tabularx

i made a table to be inserted in a paper, where it works, and i moved it to my thesis. For some reasons it gives me a series of errors i cannot understand, can you help me?
i tried copying the various package i have in my thesis tex and the table code here

```
\ifsetCustomMargin
  \RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
  \setFancyHdr

\RequirePackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For professional looking tables
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\ifuseCustomBib
   \RequirePackage{natbib}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}



\begin{table}
    \caption{Example of different attributions by three representative participants (A, B and C)}
    \label{table3}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
        \hline
        \textbf{Part A} & \textit{Sally speaking} & \textit{Narrator} & \textit{Sally speaking} & \textit{Narrator} & \textit{Sally speaking} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Oh yes, & Sally remembered; & she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie Antoinette had given her great-grandfather. & She never had a penny to her name in those days & and going to Bourton always meant some frightful pinch.\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Part B} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Sally thinking}} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Oh yes, Sally remembered; she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie} \\
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Antoinette had given her great-grandfather}
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

I also attach a capture of the errors i get[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX LaTeX SX! Could you post a compilable code?

Comment: the last row should be ended by ` \\ ` ...

Answer (score 1):

All `\hline`s in a `tabular` should be preceded by a `\\` as stated by @Zarko in a comment. I also changed the first column alignment to `l` as it's shorter than all other columns.

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{Example of different attributions by three representative participants (A, B and C)}
    \label{table3}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
        \hline
        \textbf{Part A} & \textit{Sally speaking} & \textit{Narrator} & \textit{Sally speaking} & \textit{Narrator} & \textit{Sally speaking} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Oh yes, & Sally remembered; & she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie Antoinette had given her great-grandfather. & She never had a penny to her name in those days & and going to Bourton always meant some frightful pinch.\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Part B} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Sally thinking}} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Oh yes, Sally remembered; she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie} \\
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Antoinette had given her great-grandfather} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}    
\end{table}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting `\\` before `\hline`. On the other hand, some improvements can be made on your code, for instance how to get a better `\multicolumn` for the spanned columns in part B.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Example of different attributions by three representative participants (A, B and C)}
\label{table3}

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
  @{}
  l
  *{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\textbf{Part A}
  & \textit{Sally speaking}
  & \textit{Narrator}
  & \textit{Sally speaking}
  & \textit{Narrator}
  & \textit{Sally speaking} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & Oh yes,
  & Sally remembered;
  & she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie Antoinette
    had given her great-grandfather.
  & She never had a penny to her name in those days
  & and going to Bourton always meant some frightful pinch.\\
\midrule
\textbf{Part B}
  & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Sally thinking}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & \multicolumn{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+8\tabcolsep}X@{}}{%
      Oh yes, Sally remembered; she had it still, a ruby ring which
      Marie Antoinette had given her great-grandfather} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}    

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

let me elaborate my comment ...

for reproduce your problem it is sufficient the following minimal working example (*mwe*)  :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \caption{Example of different attributions by three representative participants (A, B and C)}
    \label{table3}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
        \hline
\textbf{Part A} & \textit{Sally speaking} & \textit{Narrator} & \textit{Sally speaking} & \textit{Narrator} & \textit{Sally speaking} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & Oh yes, & Sally remembered; & she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie Antoinette had given her great-grandfather. & She never had a penny to her name in those days & and going to Bourton always meant some frightful pinch.\\
        \hline
\textbf{Part B} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Sally thinking}} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Oh yes, Sally remembered; she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie} \\
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Antoinette had given her great-grandfather}
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

where the last row is nod ended with `\\`. it is necessary when after rows you have any of rules (`\hline`, `\cline`, etc).

corrected and slightly improved *mwe* can be as follows:

[image]

since in your code is `booktabs` package, it is sensible to use it as is shown in AboAmmar answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
%    \renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \caption{Example of different attributions by three representative participants (A, B and C)}
    \label{table3}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                            >{\bfseries}l
                                   *{5}{L}
                                @{} }
        \hline
Part A
    &   \textit{Sally speaking}
        &   \textit{Narrator}
            &   \textit{Sally speaking}
                &   \textit{Narrator}
                    &   \textit{Sally speaking}                               \\
        \cline{2-6}
    &   Oh yes,
        &   Sally remembered;
            &   she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie Antoinette had given her great-grandfather.
                &   She never had a penny to her name in those days
                    &   and going to Bourton always meant some frightful pinch. \\
        \hline
Part B
    &   \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Sally thinking}}                             \\
        \cline{2-6}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{l}{Oh yes, Sally remembered; she had it still, a ruby ring which Marie} \\
    &   \multicolumn{5}{l}{Antoinette had given her great-grandfather}          \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
    \end{document}
```